# Variable in Bison is different than the one Flex returns

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

Relevant Flex part:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]* {yylval.name=yytext;printf ("Returning %s \n" ,yytext);return tID;}
```

Relevant Bison part:

```
Expr: tINTNUM 
      |tREALNUM 
      |tFALSE   
      |tTRUE    
      |tID {printf("$1 is  '%s' ",$1);}
```

My input:

```
int x; int y; begin x = 72; y=79; x=y + x; end
```

It parses fine but my issue is:

Flex prints : `Returning x` and `Returning y`

Bison prints : `$1 is 'x;'` and `$1 is 'y+'`;

Why does it append the ';'  and the '+' to the $1 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'flex', `yytext` is only a valid null-terminated string pointer during the flex action itself. You need to *copy* it to `yylval.name`, typically with `strdup(),` and make sure it gets released in the appropriate `yacc` action(s).